# Aliasing an entire resource folder with qualifiers

Tags: android, android-resources

My app includes drawable resources for mdpi through xxhdpi.  It's mainly intended for tablets, but it may occasionally be used on phones.  The problem is that my drawables take up too much screen real estate on xhdpi phones.

I'd like to set up aliases so that `xhdpi-small` devices use the `hdpi` or `mdpi` drawables.  I read [the docs](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseAliasFilters), but the examples there are pretty limited.  Is there a way to alias specific resources with qualifiers, as opposed to resources in the unqualified `drawable` folder?  And is there a way to alias the contents of an entire drawable folder, or do I have to alias each drawable individually?

**Edit: I understand that I need to create a qualified resource folder.  The question is about how to alias the resources in that folder to refer to resources in another qualified folder.**

Comment: Put the drawable resources for the tablet in the proper drawable folder (i.e.: `drawable-sw600dp`). http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @FrankN.Stein The question is about how to alias those resources so I don't have to duplicate them.

Comment: If you want only a copy of your graphic resources, then I can suggest you using SVG files. You'll need a library to open those ones, scale them and turn them into bitmaps.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I *don't* want to duplicate my graphics.  That's the point.  There is a way to do this, but it's not very well explained in the docs.

Comment: With SVGs you DON'T duplicate anything, since they are VECTORS, therefore they are SCALABLE, by definition.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein In any case, replacing the existing graphics is not an option.

Comment: Then you are condemned to duplicate your resources, manually scaling them for each density bucket... as most of us do.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I already know that's [not true](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseAliasFilters).  I just need more details.

Comment: Ah so! You were talking about `layouts`! Dunno why, but I happened to think we were talking about `drawables`... Sorry, for my `misunderstanding`.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein The question is not about layouts.  Are you implying that resource qualifiers like `small` cannot be used to qualify drawable resources or their aliases?  If so, you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Of course, you can use qualifiers such as `small`, for drawables. http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you have put drawables in each folder with proper scaling ratio(3:4:6:8:12:16).If you still have problem on small screen size then provide separate layout for small and large screen sizes.

Comment: How would a separate layout help me use the smaller drawables?

Comment: You can't force android to use specific drawable at specific dpi level.Android automatically pickup the right drawable for you according to dpi level of screen.

Comment: I understand how Android selects a qualified resource folder.  The question is about how to alias the resources so I don't have to duplicate them.